# EF: Is there way to force Linq using UNION instead of UNION ALL

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I use Linq with entity-framework.

```
GetSet1<T>().Union(GetSet2<T>())
```

The GetSetX returns IQueryable.

The generated SQL is an UNION ALL. But I know a UNION is the good way to achieve my goal. Actually my workaround is:

```
GetSet1<T>().Union(GetSet2<T>()).Distinct()
```

in this case the generated sql is like :

```
select distinct Field...
from (
    select distinct Field...
    union all
    select distinct Field...
) unionall
```

I know (because that is the way is was thinked) that

```
select Field...
union
select Field...
```

is the best query. So Is there a way (I can(t actually found) to have EntityFramework use UNION and not UNION ALL ?

==========

1: Adding the `<T>` for more precision

Comment: Maybe the two sets are provably distinct already? Although I do not see how EF would be smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Union()` method should return the result without duplicates. Depending on the query, EF will generate either `UNION ALL` with `DISTINCT` or just `UNION`, so your explicit `Distinct()` is not necessary. The Linq equivalent of `UNION ALL` is `Concat()`.

Besides that, EF has a history of generating inefficient SQL for queries. If you can, you should use EF 5.0 which has greatly improved query SQL generation.

Comment: ty. But my Profiler says UNION ALL, each time.

Comment: @tschmit007 and it doesn't say `DISTINCT` in the same query?

Comment: you'r right... it does a select ... from ( select distinct ... from (select ... union all select ...)). So finally the real question is how to union all.

Comment: The equivalent of `UNION ALL` in Linq is `Concat()`.

Comment: My guess would be that the Entity Framework omits `DISTINCT` or uses `UNION ALL` if it knows in advance that all rows are unique, for example if the primary key is contained in the column list.